# Existe diferença de performance entre retornar imagem no Controller ou na View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Acabei de aprender a buscar e exibir uma imagem do banco de dados.
Consegui fazer isso de 2 maneiras:

**Primeiro:** Através de uma ActionResult no meu Controller:

```
    public ActionResult RetornaImagemDoBanco(int id)
    {
        byte[] imageData = db.Tab_Documentos_Parente.Find(id).Documento;
        return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

E na minha View fica assim:

```
@{ string imagem = @"/Documentos_Parente/RetornaImagemDoBanco/" + Model.Id;}
<image src=@imagem alt="" />
```

**Segundo:** Diretamente na View:

```
@if (Model.Documento != null)
{
   var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Documento);
   var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
   <img src = @imgSrc alt = "" />
}
else
{
   <img src = "#" alt = "" />
}
```

Minha dúvida é: ***Existe alguma diferença significativa de performance entre esses métodos?*** Pois vou retornar uma lista de registros de alunos com suas respectivas fotos e podem ser centenas de registros.
Sugerem outra maneira?

Comment: Só testando pra saber se tem diferença.

Comment: Sinceridade, as duas são ruins, a primeira, pelo acesso a base de dados em cada foto e a segunda pela sujeira que vai gerar no seu html, agora também depende o tamanho dessas fotos em um modo geral. Talvez a segunda um pouco melhor

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Me detonou em... Kkkkk! Depois de muito pesquisar, essas são as únicas maneiras que  encontrei de exibir as imagens do banco. Mas pelo que disse nenhuma é boa. Existe outra forma?

Comment: @AlamBique, não te detonei, desculpa se foi essa impressão, mas, realmente são as formas de trazer imagens vindas de um campo na sua base, não existe outra forma não, mas, o desempenho é baixo mesmo e como você disse centenas se pode ter certeza que é ruim o desempenho. Eu trabalhei num sistema que as fotos dos alunos da faculdade eram gravados dessa mesma forma e tinha salas com 100 alunos, mas, ai eu fazia a coisa funcionar, coloquei um cache e foi até bem, então tudo depende.

Comment: Muito difícil chegar a alguma conclusão sem ter o contexto da funcionalidade.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado cara! Vou usar algum tipo de paginação pra deixar uns 15 ou menos registros por página(estou estudando o PagedList.Mvc).

Comment: @MarcellAlves a funcionalidade é a mais simples possível. Um sistema web para cadastro de alunos. Usando razor foram geradas as Views de Index, Edit, Details, Delete e Create. Modifiquei a Index para exibir as fotos de cada aluno linha por linha.

Comment: Pessoal! E se eu adicionasse uma propriedade ao modelo para receber a imagem? Essa propriedade não corresponderia a nenhuma coluna do banco existiria apenas no model (haa estou usando Entity Framework DataBase First). Então no controller eu pasaria com um Foreach as imagens para ela. Tipo assim:
foreach (aluno in Tab_Alunos){
Minha propriedade = FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");}
e já passo o model carregado para a view.
**Mas aí... Qual seria o tipo de dados dessa propriedade?**

Comment: O melhor cenário com imagens é salva-las em uma pasta ou em um FileServer, e no banco guardar apenas o caminho de acesso, esse é um cenário melhor performático, se não a melhor pratica.